# How to override the OverlayContainer provider in standalone component

Tags: angular-material

Using `{ provide: OverlayContainer, useClass: CustomOverlayContainer }` in `app.module.ts` replaces the default overlay container and it works out of the box.

But when it is  used inside a standalone component it does not work.

Does anyone know how to override the default OverlayContainer in a standalone component ?

Comment: Just digged into the same problem - I assume this is a bug in angular itself. Have you found any workaround so far?

Comment: Does the issue only happen with Angular 16?

Comment: I am using angular 14